# How can I find items with best matches tags in a desc order by comparing a tags list?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

My tables are like -
`items` table -

```
id-----item_id----name----tags--------------------------------------created_at
1------1234------test 1---["tag1", "tag2", "tag3","tag4", "tag5"]---2021-07-13 17:31:08
2------1234------test 1---["tag1", "tag2", "tag3","tag4", "tag5"]---2021-06-13 12:31:34
3------4568------test 2---["tag1", "tag4", "tag5","tag6", "tag7"]---2021-06-13 12:32:05
4------6789------test 3---["tag1", "tag3", "tag5","tag6", "tag7"]---2021-05-13 12:23:34
5------7890------test 4---["tag1", "tag4", "tag5","tag6", "tag7"]---2021-05-13 12:23:34
6------2456------test 5---["tag1", "tag2", "tag5","tag7", "tag8"]---2021-05-13 12:23:34
7------3812------test 9---["tag1", "tag2", "tag3","tag4", "tag9"]---2021-05-13 12:23:34
```

`tags` table

```
id-----name
1------tag1
2------tag2
3------tag3
4------tag4
5------tag5
6------tag6
7------tag7
8------tag8
9------tag9
```

`item_tag` table

```
id----tag_id----item_id
1-----1---------1
2-----1---------2
3-----1---------3
4-----1---------4
5-----1---------5
6-----1---------6
7-----2---------1
8-----2---------2
9-----2---------6
10----3---------1
11----3---------2
12----3---------4
13----4---------1
14----4---------2
15----4---------3
16----4---------5
```

How can I find items with best matches tags in a desc order if I want to compare them with an item! Like I want to find top 5 best matched items compared with the givent item's tag -

```
id-----item_id----name----tags--------------------------------------created_at
7------3597------test 6---["tag1", "tag2", "tag4","tag7", "tag8"]---2021-07-13 17:31:08
```

**my desired outcome will be like -**

```
item_id-------name------matched_tags
2456----------test 5----4
3812----------test 9----3
7890----------test 4----3
4568----------test 2----3
1234----------test 1----3
6789----------test 3----2
```

I tried -

```
SELECT distinct items.item_id, items.name, COUNT(items.item_id) AS tag_count
FROM items
JOIN item_tag
ON item_tag.item_id = items.id
WHERE item_tag.tag_id IN (121,126,2189,796,63,408,47,14,332,3937,27)
GROUP BY items.item_id, items.name
ORDER BY tag_count desc
```

But the problem is I have some repeated items on daily basis(**maximum items, not all**). So it returns a bigger count for repeated items-

Suppose I have an item like -

```
id-----item_id----name----tags--------------------------------------created_at
4------6789------test 3---["tag1", "tag3", "tag5","tag6", "tag7"]---2021-05-13 12:23:34
```

for 3 times. So it returns `tags_count` **6** instead of **2**

Comment: What's the query you tried and where did you run into a problem?

Comment: edited my question with what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid repeated counts, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, COUNT(dISTINCT it.tag_id) AS tag_count
FROM items i JOIN
     item_tag it
     ON it.item_id = i.id
WHERE irt.tag_id IN (121,126,2189,796,63,408,47,14,332,3937,27)
GROUP BY i.item_id, i.name
ORDER BY desc;
```

Also note that the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.